# The error comes when the sum of the numbers is negative, because the - causes an error because data isn't the same type of date

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

#My task is to create a function called sum_arrays(), which takes two arrays consisting of integers, and #returns the sum of those two arrays.

#The twist is that (for example) [3,2,9] does not equal 3 + 2 + 9, it would equal '3' + '2' + '9' #converted to an integer for this kata, meaning it would equal 329. The output should be an array of the #the sum in a similar fashion to the input (for example, if the sum is 341, you would return [3,4,1])

#[3,2,6,6],[-7,2,2,8] --> [-3,9,6,2] # 3266 + (-7228) = -3962

```
def sum_arrays(array1,array2):
    i = ""
    a = ""
    b = []
    if array1 == [] and array2 == []:
        return []
    elif array1 == []:
        return array2
    elif array2 == []:
        return array1
    else:
        for x in array1:
            i += str(x)
        for y in array2:
            a += str(y)
        sum = int(i) + int(a)
        if sum > -1:
            word = str(sum)
            for z in word:
                p = int(z)
                b.append(p)
            return b
        else:
            word = str(sum)
            for z in word[1:]:
                p = int(z)
                b.append(p)
                l = b[0] * -1
                b.append(l)
            return b[1:-1]

print(sum_arrays([3, 2, 9], [1, 2]))
print(sum_arrays([4,7,3],[1,2,3]))
print(sum_arrays([],[]))
print(sum_arrays([-9, 8],[0, 2, 0]))
print(sum_arrays([-9, 8, 3, 4],[0, 2, 0, 8]))
```

Comment: what is ```#[3,2,6,6],[-7,2,2,8] --> [-3,9,6,2] # 3266 + (-7228) = -3962``` this meant to mean?

Comment: This is an example of how the code should work if the sum of the numbers is negative. So those arrays should be converted to integers first and then the sum is the answer. The answer then has to be converted to an array again.

Comment: so my answer basically ?

Comment: What's all the `#` suppose to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the list to a string and remove the `,`, `[` and `]`. Then convert them back to integers, and perform the operation.

```
def sum_arrays(array1,array2):
    if array1 == [] and array2 == []:
        return []
    elif array1 == []:
        return array2
    elif array2 == []:
        return array1
    else:
        a = str(array1).replace(', ','').replace('[','').replace(']','')
        b = str(array2).replace(', ','').replace('[','').replace(']','')
        summ = int(a) + int(b)
        
return [int('-'+x) if n == 1 else int(x) for n,x in enumerate(str(summ)) if x.isdigit()] if '-' in str(summ) else [int(x) for x in str(summ) if x.isdigit()]


print(sum_arrays([3,2,6,6],[-7,2,2,8]))

>>> [-3, 9, 6, 2]
```

Comment: The answer I want to return is in array form. Not in the int type .And this answer only give and int back and not the array form.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that after creating the string from a negative number you try to convert something like `['-','5', ...]` to int. Single `'-'` cannot be converted to int.

---

You can essentially do this with far less code then you did:

```
def toArr(num):
    """Returns list of digits (as ints) of a number, handling negatives correctly."""
    negative = num < 0
    nums = list(map(int, str(abs(num))))
    if negative:
        nums[0] *= -1
    return nums

def sum_arrays(arr1, arr2):
    # handle one or two empty inputs 
    if not arr1 or not arr2:
        return arr1 or arr2
    # do the work
    return toArr(int(''.join(map(str, arr1))) + int(''.join(map(str, arr2))))

print(sum_arrays([-7,9,8,2],[9,9,9]))
print(sum_arrays([3, 2, 9], [1, 2]))
print(sum_arrays([4,7,3],[1,2,3]))
print(sum_arrays([],[]))
print(sum_arrays([-9, 8],[0, 2, 0]))
print(sum_arrays([-9, 8, 3, 4],[0, 2, 0, 8]))
```

Output:

```
[-6, 9, 8, 3] 
[3, 4, 1]
[5, 9, 6]
[]
[-7, 8]
[-9, 6, 2, 6]
```

Output:

```
[-6, 9, 8, 3]
```

---

Explanations of `int(''.join(map(str, arr1))) + int(''.join(map(str, arr2)))`:

This does the same thing twice:

- convert each single number of the input array (`arr1` / `arr2`) to strings
- concattenate the strings
- convert to int
- add it to the same for the other array

The result is an integer that is then fed to `toArr` which

- decides if the number is negative
- converts the numbers absolute values to strings and converts each digit to an integer
- fixes the first number to be negative if needed